# Inspect mobile app elements by connecting to xamarin test cloud real devices

Tags: xamarin, appium, xamarin-test-cloud

I want to write Appium script using JAVA for mobile app automation. How do I inspect the mobile elements using Xamarin. I need yo use physical device. In my organization the USB ports are blocked so I can not connect any. Application doesn't work on emulators. Is it possible to connect to xamarin test cloud device and inspect the app? If yes, then how to do that?

Comment: you can run ADB over wifi

Comment: There once was a feature called Xamarin Test Cloud Live but it did not appear after the announcement. So my opinion is: No you can not inspect the app through Test Cloud.